# Numerical variable coloured as range in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data

I need this graph to colour by "potsize" as a categorical variable, rather than a numerical range. The pot sizes are 2.5, 5, 10, 20, and 40 litres, so ggplot2 produces a graph with shades of blue, rather than more distinct colours. I'm sure this is a very simple problem, but I'm very new to R. I have tried to find solutions, but most result in the create of discrete bins based on ranges, rather than discrete categories based on individual numbers.

```
# Graph mean leaf greenness in all pots over time.

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = greenness.average..., col = potsize)) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: You need to make `potsize` a factor. At a minimum, `col = factor(potsize)` should work, but you can create the factor outside of the ggplot call too. Separately, it looks like something weird is going on with your variable naming as `greenness.average...` is not a good name.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: If you are using pipes, `df %>% mutate(potsize = factor(potsize)) %>% ggplot(etc)`.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).